# Complex polynomial that sends real line to real line, positive imaginary part to positive imaginary part, negative imaginary part to...

Tags: complex-analysis

Let p be a polynomial that sends points on the real line to points on the real line, sends points with positive imaginary part to points with positive imaginary part, and sends points with negative imaginary part to points with negative imaginary part. Prove that p must be of the form $p(z)=az+b$ where a is a positive number and b is a real number.

Since p maps the real line to the real line, all coefficients are real. From what else we're given, we can also deduce that all zeros are real. This is where I get stuck. I thought about the fundamental theorem of algebra but couldn't get anywhere with it. I feel like I'm missing something obvious. Any hints?

Comment: How do you know that all coefficients are real?

Comment: I was thinking that if one of them is complex, then some real number would get mapped to a complex number. (just by plugging stuff in) Maybe I'm wrong about that though.

Comment: If $z$ has nonzero imaginary part, it cannot map to zero.

Comment: What if $p$ maps integers into integers? Would you deduce that the coefficients are integers? I hope not, because $\frac12z^2+\frac12z$ maps integers into integers.

Comment: Guess I'm wrong then. @Joe I know that much.

Comment: If you know all zeros are real, and the fundamental theorem of algebra, then it shouldn't take much to show all coefficients are real.

Comment: Okay, I see that much. But now we're back to where I'm stuck. lol

Comment: If you consider a point $c+di$ where $c$ is larger than any zero, and $d>0$ becomes large enough, then I think polar form of the decomposed polynomial will give you your result for $n>2$, meaning there will be a $d$ that maps to a real number.

Comment: For $n=2$, I think you can choose $c+di$ so that $c$ is the average of the zeros, and $d\ne 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$p$ nonconstant clearly and if $x_1,..x_n$ are its roots the property of $p$ means $x_k \in \mathbb R$ since $p(x_k)=0$ and then $P(z)=a(z-x_1)..(z-x_k)$ and $a \in \mathbb R, a \ne 0$ by taking $z=x$ not a root and using $0 \ne P(x) \in \mathbb R$

But then there is a large $C$ st $|p'(x)| >0, |x| >C$ hence $p$ is strictly monotonic on $\mathbb R -[-C,C]$ and $|p| \to \infty$ at $\pm \infty$; if the degree of $p$ is even it follows that $p$ cannot be surjective on the reals (has either a global min or a global max depending whether $a>0$ or $a<0$ as the limits at $\pm \infty$ of $p$ are same sign infinity) so since by the fundamental theorem of algebra $p(z)=b$ has roots for all real $b$ there is such $b$ for which the roots are complex non real which is a contradiction

If $p$ has odd degree, then outside $p([-C,C]$) compact set $p$ can take any value only once so again if the degree is $3$ or higher there are complex non real roots to  $p(z)=b$ for some real $b$ with $|b|$ large enough and that is not possible.

Hence $p=az+b,a.b \in \mathbb R$ and then the orientation property (upper plane to upper plane) shows $a>0$